# How do I specify webpath on apache 2.2 on windows?

Tags: windows, apache, url, alias

I need apache to serve a public site and a private site. The public site is under `DocumentRoot` and the private site is on another folder structure.

I was reading that I need to specify Alias if I want to server pages that are not under the DocumentRoot. How to do I specify Alias?

```
Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
```

I am using apache on Windows. If my files are at `C:\Testsite\site` how do I get apache to serve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to set webpath as files, try this

```
Alias /files c:/Testsite/site
<Directory "c:/Testsite/site"> 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```